# Protobuf-net [de]serialize GameObject (Unity 3D)

Tags: protobuf-net

In Unity 3D, there is a GameObject with a Transform property. Transform has position (Vector3) and rotation (Quaternion). I would like to send these GameObjects to/from a backing store via protobuf-net. I am currently doing so with the following code but the GameObject.transform.position.x,y,z and transform.rotation.x,y,z,w don't appear to be stored in the serialized file?

```
RuntimeTypeModel model = TypeModel.Create();
model.AutoAddMissingTypes = true;
model.Add(typeof(Vector3), true).Add("x","y","z");
model.Add(typeof(Transform), true).Add("position").Add("rotation"); 
model.Add(typeof(Quaternion), true).Add("x","y","z","w");
model.Add(typeof(GameObject), true).Add("transform").Add("name");
model.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(fs, go, typeof(GameObject), PrefixStyle.Base128, 0);
```

Deserialize:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
fs.Position = 0;
RuntimeTypeModel model = TypeModel.Create();
model.AutoAddMissingTypes = true;
model.Add(typeof(Vector3), true).Add("x","y","z");
model.Add(typeof(Transform), true).Add("position").Add("rotation"); ;
model.Add(typeof(Quaternion), true).Add("x","y","z","w");
model.Add(typeof(GameObject), true).Add("transform").Add("name");

 do
 {
   len = ProtoReader.ReadLengthPrefix(fs, false, PrefixStyle.Base128, out fieldNumber, out bytesRead);
   if (bytesRead <= 0) continue;

   gos.Add((GameObject)model.Deserialize(fs, null, typeof(GameObject), len));
 } while (bytesRead > 0);
}
```

I appear to be getting back the correct number of GameObjects but the only thing that is correct on deserialization is the .name property. The sub-properties of the Transform class aren't being translated with my current code.  Any ideas would be super helpful!
Thanks-

## EDIT

Based on my comment, here is the stack trace:

```
at (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.Object.set_name (string) <0x00004>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) UnityEngine.Transform.proto_22 (object,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader) <IL 0x0002f, 0x00137>
at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read (object,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader) <IL 0x00008, 0x0002f>
at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize (int,object,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader) <IL 0x0003d, 0x00143>
at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject (object,int,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader,System.Type) <IL 0x0002d, 0x000f6>
at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject (object,int,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader) <IL 0x00004, 0x00031>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) CoreStructure.proto_20 (object,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader) <IL 0x000e5, 0x005cb>
at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read (object,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader) <IL 0x00008, 0x0002f>
at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize (int,object,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader) <IL 0x0003d, 0x00143>
at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject (object,int,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader,System.Type) <IL 0x0002d, 0x000f6>
at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject (object,int,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader) <IL 0x00004, 0x00031>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) CharacterPoseSet.proto_14 (object,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader) <IL 0x00116, 0x006e0>
at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read (object,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader) <IL 0x00008, 0x0002f>
at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize (int,object,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader) <IL 0x0003d, 0x00143>
at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore (ProtoBuf.ProtoReader,System.Type,object,bool) <IL 0x00011, 0x00073>
at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream,object,System.Type,ProtoBuf.SerializationContext) <IL 0x00022, 0x000ff>
at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream,object,System.Type) <IL 0x00005, 0x0003e>
at PoseEditor.DeserializeCharacterPoseSet () [0x0015f] in C:\My Work\KungFuKitty\UnityWorkspace\Assets\Scripts\Editor\PoseBuilder\PoseEditor.cs:137

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
PoseEditor:DeserializeCharacterPoseSet() (at Assets/Scripts/Editor/PoseBuilder/PoseEditor.cs:160)
PoseEditor:OnGUI() (at Assets/Scripts/Editor/PoseBuilder/PoseEditor.cs:98)
PoseBuilder:OnGUI() (at Assets/Scripts/Editor/PoseBuilder/PoseBuilder.cs:128)
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()
```

## Deserialization:

```
RuntimeTypeModel model = TypeModel.Create();
model.AutoAddMissingTypes = false;
model.Add(typeof(CharacterPoseSet), true);  
model.Add(typeof(LegStructure), true);
model.Add(typeof(ArmStructure), true);
model.Add(typeof(AuxilaryStructure), true);
model.Add(typeof(CoreStructure), true);
model.Add(typeof(Vector3), true).Add("x", "y", "z");           <-- UnityEngine
model.Add(typeof(Transform), true).Add("name");                <-- UnityEngine
model.Add(typeof(Quaternion), true).Add("x", "y", "z", "w");   <-- UnityEngine
model.Add(typeof(GameObject), true).Add("transform").Add("name").Add("layer"); <--..
cps = model.Deserialize(fs, cps, typeof(CharacterPoseSet)) as CharacterPoseSet;
```

This is on PC/Windows 7 Box.. all code is executing inside the Unity editor.

Comment: I'm not a Unity 3D expert, and I understand that it is available for multiple platforms. To answer this, I'd really need to be able to take a look at this "in action" - can you clarify which platform you are targetting, so I can investigate?

Comment: @MarcGravell : I got this working if I reference the GameObject as a property in my class but the Transform class appears to be an issue across boundaries.  Thanks again for looking into this.